# Java JOptionPane Dialog NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dialog, joptionpane

The following code runs perfectly,but if you click "x" or "cancel" on the dialog `NullPointerException` is thrown. I am trying to recall the method `TestMessage` and go back to the same dialog.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Alpha {

  public void TestMessage() {

    Object [] tM1={"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"};

    String mA2 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"This is a test Message",null, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,tM1,tM1[0]);

    if (mA2.equals("Option 1")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose Option 1");}
    if (mA2.equals("Option 2")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose Option 2");}
    if (mA2.equals("Option 3")) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You chose Option 3");}

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {

    Alpha A1=new Alpha();
    A1.TestMessage();

    }

    }
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Alpha.TestMessage(Alpha.java:11)
at Alpha.main(Alpha.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: Which lines are 11 and 20? if I had to guess I'd say `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"This is a test Message",null, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,tM1,tM1[0]);` is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showInputDialog` returns `null` if you press 'Cancel' or 'X' so your check `if (mA2.equals("Option 1")` accesses a `null` pointer.
Just check  `mA2 != null` before.